# How to improve from too broad question to answerable question

Tags: discussion, questions

I have asked in a general/broad way [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/225677/105234) thinking that as related to [What skills are required to perform large scale statistical analyses?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/7815/105234) would be well received and useful for me. Then the comments were that it needs (far) more editing to make it useful and answerable here.
Now that I have edited to include more information perhaps I have been too specific.

How much details should I add?
Is the question, interpreting the results on-topic?

Comment: Your question is not a statistical one.  Here it is, *verbatim*: "What happens in the the cells in the conditions studied?"  That's not on-topic on this site.

Comment: That's the question I am trying to answer on my study, not the question I am asking here on CV

Comment: Interpreting the results of a statistical analysis demands a degree of subject matter knowledge. In the case of your question on CV we cannot see any statistical questions left over and above the genetics questions.